# php: odbc_connect(): SQL error

Tags: php, sql, tcp

I have a big problem connecting my php page which is running **on the same** PC as my SQL Server with the SQL server and execute things...

Maybe this following warning will help you:

Warning: odbc_connect(): SQL error: [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0]Named Pipes Provider: Could not open a connection to SQL Server [53]. , SQL state 08001 in SQLConnect in *MY_CONFIG_FILE* on line 9

I wonder what causes this problem as the webserver with the php page is running on the same machine as my SQL server does.

I´m using this code:

```
odbc_connect("Driver={SQL Server Native Client 11.0};Server='MY_IP';Database='MY_DATABASE';", 'MY_SQL_USER', 'THE_PW_OF_MY_SQL_USER');
```

What I have tried so far:

1. Adding the IP to the host file of Windows
2. Switching the complete firewall off
3. adding a User-DSN ODBC Connection called SQLEXPRESS with a working connectivity test
4. Connecting from my home PC with SQL Management Studio to the SQL Server. It worked with the same login data and IP which I´ve added in the SQL Config File.
5. Enabling TCP/IP and Named Pipes in the SQL Management Studio on port 1433
6. Restarting everything several times (Professional Solution, I know ;))
7. enabling TCP/IP and Named Pipes in the cliconfg.exe

I hope there are some gurus here which can help me :)

Thx a lot in advance ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I´m sorry for the troubles.

The problem was, that I was using `SQL Server Native Client 11.0` as driver.
I switched it to `SQL Server` and now it works :/

Hopefully this at least helps someone, being in a similar problem....